# Capitalization using C

Tags: c

This my program where I capitalize every word of the input. But the problem is the output I am getting is not correct.
This is my input

```
"A professor invites me to his “Black Lit” class; they’re
reading Larson’s Passing. One of the black
students says, “Sometimes light-skinned blacks
think they can fool other blacks,
but I can always tell,” looking
right through me.#"
```

And this is my output

```
"A professor invites me to his “Black Lit” class; they’re
A Professor Invites Me To His "Black Lit" Class; They're reading Larson’s Passing. One of the black
Reading Larson's Passing. One Of The Black students says, “Sometimes light-skinned blacks
Students Says, "Sometimes Light-skinned Blacks think they can fool other blacks,
Think They Can Fool Other Blacks, but I can always tell,” looking
But I Can Always Tell," Looking right through me."
```

My question is How can I get a more nice output where for every line of input I get the output exactly after each input line and along with output for the last line where the program I did not get the output?
Thank you very much.
My code is below`enter code here:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void read_and_capitalize() {
    int character;
    //Get the first character from the user
    printf("\n");

    character = getchar();
    if (isspace(character)) {
        while (isspace(character)) {
            character = getchar();

        }

        character = getchar();
    }

    while (character != '#') {
        if (isspace(character)) {
            printf(" ");
            while (isspace(character)) {
                character = getchar();
            }
            printf("%c", toupper(character));
            character = getchar();

        }
            else {
                printf("%c", character);
                character = getchar();
            }


        }
    }



    int main(void){
        read_and_capitalize();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Your leading space code skips the first non-space character.  You don't want the final `character = getchar();` after that `while` loop — the loop test failed when it got a non-space character.

Comment: The problem is that newline is treated as a 'space' character by `isspace()`, so you don't necessarily echo the newlines in the input.  You're getting input interspersed with output; that's a problem with terminal input.  Maybe you should read lines with `fgets()` and then process the character array containing the characters.  Also there's a problem with leading punctuation getting in the way of capitalization.  If you have input `a word "double quoted"`, you'd probably get `A Word "double Quoted"` as output.

Comment: Your solution is overly complicated. You need to (1) read a character (2) decide if it's the first character of a word (3) output the (possibly capitalised) character. This is a single `while` loop, and a single call to `getchar` inside that loop, and a single call to `printf` or `putchar` or whatever you decide to use inside the loop. The only program-specific logic is in the decision whether to capitalise a character, which you need to figure out yourself.

Comment: I suggest using the function `isalpha` (declared as `int isalpha(int c)`, include `ctype.h`), which returns `true` if the argument is a letter.

Comment: @user_194421 No, `isspace` is apprpriate considering the given example in-/output; `they're` or `Larson's` would get `They'Re` and `Larson'S` otherwise, which apparently is not the desired output...

Comment: @Aconcagua But not all letters come after a space, there are ones which come after a quotation mark. So I think they should use them _in conjunction_.

Comment: @Aconcagua he means use `isalpha` to determine whether to capitalize a character; not determine word separation. This program seems to be assuming the former indicates the latter. In reality it only means its time to start *looking* for something appropriate to capitalize, which may *not* necessarily be the next non-whitespace character. I concur with that, btw.

Comment: @Aconcagua we know nothing about the language of the input. Perhaps in English `s` after an apostrophe is not considered a separate word, but in some other language a similar character combination should be treated as a separate word, or does not exist at all. Hence one should start from making a clear unambiguous definition of what is considered a word, and then use it in the program logic. It is not easy to come up with a reasonable definition that would satisfy a cunning linguist.

Comment: Hm, if English examples are given, is it fair to assume English input, if nothing else denoted? I did so, at least. Different languages might come with *conflicting* rules: `they're` gets `They're`, but in French, `j'essaie` needs to get `J'Essaie` (E: first latter of second word dropped; F: last letter of first word dropped: `je essaie` - side note: the latter invalid as in F, contraction is mandatory). The `'s` example in English looks more complex anyway; sure, it can denote *genitive* only (no separate word), but what about `it's`?

Comment: Admitted, no native English speaker, I would consider this as two words as in my mother tongue (German: `Ich hab's`, short for `Ich habe es` counts as three words) -- what would be the NES view? Based on *my/German* view, still no captitalisation, as the word's first letter is dropped, so we'd have to capitalize the apostrophe replacing the 'i'... Considering that 'light-skinned' shall get 'Light-skinned' (that one I would have done differently myself...), the quotes and the rest of the examples, all this driving me to the following proposition:

Comment: `if(isspace) { isCapitalize = true; } else if(isalpha) { toupper; isCapitalize = false; } else { /* just do not consider for capitalization */}`. Looks to me, as if this would fit the given example quite well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you don't print the newlines as `isspace` will be true for `\n`.

So a simple change to your code could be to change this line:

```
while (character != '#') {
```

into these lines

```
while (character != '#') {
    if (character == '\n')
    {
            printf("%c", character);
            character = getchar();
            continue;
    }
```

That said, I think you should consider a redesign to simplify the code. By introducing some state variable to tell whether you have a) just printed a space/newline and b) whether you need to use `toupper` on the next print of
a non-space character.

It could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_and_capitalize() 
{
    int character;
    int make_upper = 1;  // Explanation
                         // 1 means: "Don't echo a space"
                         //          "Call toupper on non-space characters"
                         //
                         // 0 means: "Echo a space"
                         //          "Don't call toupper on non-space characters"

    printf("\n");

    //Get the first character from the user
    character = getchar();
    while (character != '#') 
    {
        if (character == '\n')
        {
            printf("%c", character);
            make_upper = 1;
        }
        else if (isspace(character)) 
        {
            if (!make_upper) printf(" ");
            make_upper = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%c", make_upper ? toupper(character) : character);
            make_upper = 0;
         }
         character = getchar();
     }
}

int main(void)
{
    read_and_capitalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this code works but only problem i am facing now is I am not getting the output for the last line  which has # in it.